# Individual Email results records

Tags: marketing-cloud-connect

We have set up journey in Marketing Cloud using Salesforce data as an entry source. I am observing individual email results records in Sales cloud and found that some of them have not flown back to Sales Cloud.
In Email studio tracking I see total sent (delivered) are 35, while I only see 13 IERs in Sales cloud. Some of the email were sent 5 days ago. I assume that it won't take that long for the tracking to flow into Sales Cloud.
Does anyone have any ideas why this happens?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can request tracking immediately, to see if it can pull over the tracking data - if this works, then you know the connector is working.

If it doesn't flow over, it means there's an issue with your connector - and a support case would be the best way to resolve. (Can be a number of things, out of date oauth token, a bug, other)

Comment: Thank you Kenneth, I logged a case and MC support team told me that this is a known issue.

Comment: Hi HRJ, do you know the number of the issue or a link where the issue is explained? Thanks!